# Multiple Loops / WP_Query on One Page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm attempting to have two loops on my archive-custom.php (it's for a custom post type) - one loop for featured post(s) and another for the rest of the posts.

This is the code I have come up with, however, it's not working correctly. At the moment, it doesn't display either loop and ends up actually breaking other PHP based elements.

Note: These loops are split up into different template parts - not sure if that matters or not. However, I have combined them into one chunk to make it easier to troubleshoot.

```
<?php $args = array (
    'post_type' => 'community',
    'category_name' => 'featured',);
    // The Query
    $community_posts_featured = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ($community_posts_featured->have_posts()) : while ($community_posts_featured->have_posts()) : $community_posts_featured->the_post(); ?>  

    <div id="featured">
        <--Featured Stuff Here-->
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div><!--End #featured-->

<?php endwhile; ?>  

<?php $args = array (
'post_type' => 'community', );
// The Query
$community_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($community_posts->have_posts()) : while ($community_posts->have_posts()) : $community_posts->the_post(); ?>

<div id="main-content">
    <--Main Stuff Here-->
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div><!--#End Main-->              

<?php endwhile; ?>  

<?php else : ?>
     <--Missing Content Stuff-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The first `endif;` is never closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There i can spot two problems:
1) You have opened 2 if statements and have just closed one of them
2) you'd better use `wp_reset_query();` after the first loop